# Android PreferenceFragment pre 3.0

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I recently downloaded the newest update to the Android SDK, and I realized that `addPreferencesFromResource(int resourceID)`, `findPreference(String preference)`, and `getPreferenceScreen()` within `PreferenceActivity` have been depreciated in favor of `PreferenceFragment` and its implementation of `addPreferencesFromResource(int resourceID)`

This is fine, and I was able to re-write all of my preference screens to be able to use the new standard of `PreferenceFragment` for 4.x devices. The problem, however, is that the `PreferenceFragment` screens do not show on Android 2.3 or before. When the preference screen is opened, it literally shows a blank screen. So now I have a check for which SDK the device is using, and displaying the `PreferenceFragment` if the device is 3.0+, or displaying the old depreciated way if it's pre 3.0.

Is there a better way to do this? I don't want to be using depreciated code if there is a way to get the `PreferenceFragment` code working properly in 2.2 and 2.3. Is there is a new standard way of doing this in pre-3.0 devices without using depreciated code? (My app is designed for 2.2+, and I would like to continue to support back to 2.2 for a larger user base)

If someone can point me in the right direction, I can do the leg work from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the [compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) (designed for API 4+) does not support the PreferenceFragment - so what you have is probably the best solution until you're comfortable putting your target API up to 11.

Comment: I guess that works for now. It looks like they update that compatibility library every few months, so I guess I'll just keep an eye on that and hopefully they'll add something in there soon. Thanks for the response! :-)